# Understanding of Definition of Field Homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $(F,+,.)$ and $(K,\oplus,\odot)$ be two fields. The map $f:F\rightarrow K$ is called *field homomorphism*, if for all $a,b\in F:$

$f\left( a+b\right) =f\left( a\right) \oplus f\left(b\right)$,

$f\left( a.b\right) =f\left( a\right)\odot f\left( b\right)$.

> **My question is**:What is difference between $+$ and $\oplus$ also, $.$ and $\odot$?

Comment: Take an example : $f(x+iy) = (x,y)$ is a field homomorphism $(\mathbb{C},+,.) \to (\mathbb{R}^2,+,\times)$ where the multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(a,b)\times(c,d)=(ac-bd,bc+ad)$

Comment: The addition and multiplication operations in $K$ are notated differently (encircled) in order to distinguish them from the field operations on $F$ (this is esp. helpful when $F$ and $K$ are the same sets)

Comment: They are all just binary operations. Different symbols are used to emphasize that they don't all need to be the same binary operations.

Comment: You forgot  to add to your two requirements the condition that $f(1_F)=1_K$. That condition  does **not** follow from  your two requirements and is absolutely indispensable: the zero map is **not** a field homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$+$ is a binary operation on $F$ such that $(F,+)$ forms an abelian additive group.

$\oplus$ is a binary operation on $K$ such that $(K,+)$ forms an abelian additive group.

Similarly $\odot$ is a binary operation on $K$ such that $(K\setminus\{0\},\odot)$ forms an abelian multiplicative group.

$.$ is a binary operation on $K$ such that $(F\setminus\{0\},.)$ forms an abelian multiplicative group.

Comment: But, I couldn't see a difference.

Comment: The difference is that the sets are fields under different binary operations